# LOG4J2: how to configure JSON layout in properties file

Tags: json, jackson, log4j, log4j2

Does anyone know, how to write a log4j2 properties file, which outputs the logs to the console as JSON ?

i saw this link, https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout, but it is not clear for me, how do the configuration in a properties file.

thanks,
Eran

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore, some options can be set in the log4j2.properties:

```
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=myLog.json
appender.file.layout.type=JsonLayout
appender.file.layout.compact=true
appender.file.layout.eventEol=true
appender.file.layout.complete=true
appender.file.layout.properties=false
appender.file.layout.propertiesAsList=false
appender.file.layout.locationInfo=true
appender.file.layout.includeStacktrace=true
appender.file.layout.stacktraceAsString=true
appender.file.layout.includeNullDelimiter=false
appender.file.layout.objectMessageAsJsonObject=true
```

Please refer to the log4j2 documentation for the properties definition:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout

Answer (score 1):

I found this [Tutorial](https://springframework.guru/log4j-2-configuration-using-properties-file/) from the Springframework guru. My `log4j2.properties` file looks as follows;

```
name=JsonConfig

appenders = file

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=myLog.json
appender.file.layout.type=JsonLayout

loggers=file
logger.file.name=your.logger.package.location
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
```

Hope this helps.